# Running MeteorJS on remote server

Tags: meteor

I like to do my development over SSH on a remote server -- is there any way to run and access meteor's debug server in that situation?

It listens for http://localhost://3000, not on http://example.com://3000, so I can't access it.

Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, I ran a default meteor server earlier today on OSX and had a coworker hit it from his browser; this worked fine.  This is likely OS-dependent behavior. It's also possible that it was listening on all interfaces and simply reporting "localhost" to the console.

Comment: +1 for Benson's response, I think this was either OS (Ubuntu) or more likely environment specific to that particular machine. I was unable to replicate it elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I just found the code in app/meteor/run.js and hardcoded the Status.listening statement's host value to my host, and it worked for now! Perhaps --host can be added as an option to "meteor run" in the future as a sustainable solution.

Answer (score 1):

you could also do an ssh local port forward, more information is [here](http://magazine.redhat.com/2007/11/06/ssh-port-forwarding/#local).